# Processing & writing bulkified validation using more than 50k records

Tags: apex, map, bulkification, collection

I have two fields in my Opportunity object: Phone_1__c & Phone_2__c. Now I have to check to check the whole Org, if there are any opportunities made earlier using any of these two numbers. (Org has more than 53k records).

Attempt:1

I added the `Phone_1__c` & `Phone_2__c` to the list and performed SOQL using that

```
[SELECT count() FROM Opportunity
                            WHERE (Phone_1__c IN :oppAddOnPhoneList
                            OR Phone_2__c IN :oppAddOnPhoneList)
```

`oppAddOnPhoneList` : list containing Phone numbers of all current Opportunities.

Now the problem is, this code works fine for single opportunity. It will not work for a `list<Opportunities>` containing new phone number and existing phone number, as the `oppAddOnPhoneList` always has some existing phone number present.
Any suggestions /ideas to bulkify this code?

Note: I will also add other filters in SOQL ( Stage, createddate etc..,)
      Batch apex will run asynchronously. But I need to throw the error instantly. Read about the @readOnly annotation. But does it need vf page?

Comment: This query is already bulkified, what I understood is you want to compare List of new phone no with List of existing phone no, is that correct?

Comment: @sagarmaurya : Yes, I'll be comparing new phone number with existing one. But  when passed List<opportunity>, I couldn't separate which phone number among the new is existing and which are not, so that I could throw error to the duplicates alone

Comment: You will have to iterate over the each Opportunity with new phone no and compare them with List of existing Opportunity having phone no.

Comment: Is it the only possible solution?? Because to compare with existing phone number I might have to fetch all phone number from my org ( > 50k, even with all filters & conditions). That's why I tried count() instead

Comment: Yes, I can think of this solution. If this is the case, you can use batch class.

Comment: Thanks Sagar. I'm checking the feasibility of batch as well as @ReadOnly annotation, as I don't have any DML. I need to just compare old data with new data